# What are "analyze", "test" and other checkboxes in "Build" part of scheme in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I understand that when I run Project -> Build, it does what I set in "Build" part of current scheme. I see my targets there, so I want to choose which target to build. But there are checkboxes near each target. I can't get what do they do..

Here is screenshot:
[image: checkboxes]

Answer (score 1):

Analyze performs static code analysis.

Test runs your unit tests.

Run runs your application.

Profile runs a profiling application for measuring speed.

Archive creates an archive of your built app, for installing on devices or for uploading to the App Store.

Comment: Thanks, but how does it connected with "build" checkboxes? What will happen if I check or uncheck checkbox "tests" in my "Build" confiig?

Comment: This has never made sense to me either.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell these allow you to build your project for various purposes, Running, Profiling, Archiving, etc.

Try unchecking the `Profiling` checkbox then building your project for Profiling `Product -> Build For -> Profiling (Shift+Cmd+I)`. You will get an error stating `Your scheme XXX is not configured for Profiling`.

So I guess it's just simply a way to enable or disable different types of builds.